# 524 Error and Jupyterlab api status - Unhealthy

Tags: google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

How can we solve below error on GCP JupyterLab? tried already available solutions on stackoverflow + google cloud but none of them working. Please help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfVWt.png

Comment: Could you mention which troubleshooting steps you've tried so far?  Also could you share screenshot of the result of these commands `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/kernelspecs` and 
`sudo service jupyter restart` ?

Comment: Please describe "available solutions" so we know what have you tried.  Can you share the DLVM version (Notebooks version), it should be available in Notebook details page or Compute Instance metadata? This is a known issue in older images with containers, but please add more details.

Comment: I've got a very similar issue, and open another thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326566/jupyter-internal-api-is-not-active-vertex-ai-jupyterlab-error-524